# Why in some linear transformations, space is flipped?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Watching [3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE&list=PL0-GT3co4r2y2YErbmuJw2L5tW4Ew2O5B&index=4) video on geometric meaning of Matrix transformations, there was a matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$

Which meant that, the $i$ will move to new coordinates $[1 , 2 ]$, which indeed made the x-axis oblique and moved $i$ to $[1,2}]$.

But after that when moving $j$ to $[3,1]$, the space was flipped first and then the $y$ axis were made to rotate so as to move $j$ to $[3,1]$.

I was confused in that. Because if at all we are just to move $i$ and $j$ to new co-ordinates, we can indeed do that without flipping.

What am I missing? please help.

the exact timestamp is 9:20

Thank you !

Comment: To think about the title question, try considering the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$Have you learned about eigenvectors yet? If so, I think the easiest answer to give would involve the fact that the matrix in your question has one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @Joe The space would be flipped, whatever I can see is when the basis is to move to other half of space crossing the origin? It can directly move to any point in its half (or side of origin) but crossing origin need flipping?

Comment: @Joe yes eigen values I know (that is what I believe). But are you changing the basis vectors in terms of eigen vectors (linear combination), and then seeing the transformation? Thereby coming significance of negative eigenvalues?

Comment: There are matrices that are rotations, which can send vectors to other quadrants. But if a matrix has an eigenvector with a negative eigenvalue, that vector gets reflected across the hyperplane (line in 2D) that it is normal to.

Comment: Have you learned about singular value decomposition? That shows that every linear transformation can be viewed as three successive operations: (1) rotations/reflections, (2) scaling, (3) rotations/reflections

Comment: @Joe Ok! please help me in where I am lacking visualization please. I am seeing original vector space and then the matrix as  representing a linear transformation, i.e. changing the grid lines to new parallels in the transformed vector-space. Thus, if we can really see the  mapping of each point in original space to its image in  the transformed space, we can put aside the matrix and do with the mapping thing. So, in that context, I do see that eigen vector span with negative eigen-value will surely be transformed to flipped vector-span across the normal plane. But why the whole space?

Comment: @Joe that is yet to be done! Sorry. I am yet at eigen vectors and diagonilazation. SVD is not done.

Comment: If the matrix is "diagonalizable", meaning that the $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then every vector in the space is a linear combination of the eigenvectors. The action of the matrix on any vector in the space is determined by the action of the matrix on each of the eigenvectors.

Comment: To anyone trying to help!! While imagining the transformation of space (from original to transformed), I am seeing the point that whenever we transform on set of gridlines (say x-axis), and if the new destination of $j$ is such that we need to cross the transformed $i$, we do not cut through the transformed $i$ but we instead flip the whole space, so that the $j$ get to move to its desired destination in transformed space, but without cutting.  I want to know WHY this? Secondly we could transform any of $i$ or $j$ first and would need to cross initial while transforming the other, so we flip

Comment: @Joe yes seeing it! So, if its diagonalizable , then like $j$ was a basis in original coordinate system, now is the eigenvector $v$ and if this $v$ has a negative eigenvalue, its flipped like if $i$ was moving to $-i$, it had to be flipped.  This picture from eigen negative value leading to flipping seems clear. But when not diagonalizable? Then how negative eigen value would mean flipping? Thanks

Comment: When it is not diagonalizable, every eigenvalue has a space of generalized eigenvectors, but I am not sure how to "picture" the transformation. Even when the eigenvectors are complex, I am not sure how to "picture" it, other than through the SVD. Maybe someone else will provide a detailed answer.

Comment: "if at all we are just to move $i$ and $j$ to new co-ordinates, we can indeed do that without flipping."  I don't see a way to do that.  $i$ was on the right-hand side before, but it turned to the left-hand side after the transformation.  Did you move the vectors off the origin?

Comment: @L.F. no I had origin intact. But I saw it as just gliding of $j$ wherever it was (basically at 1 unit in y-axis ) to the vector $[3,1]$. Yes, I am getting that this is somewhat fishy and the right-left logic that you are seeing through might be the reasoning. Still I want to ask that, see for $j$ all that we want to do is to move it to a new position. So. what I did was hold the tip of vector $j$ from $[0,1]$ and glide it to left to the point $[3,1]$. I could do that without any flipping, but we need flipping! Why? Thank you

Comment: @Joe thank you! It greatluy helped. Yes when matrix is not diagonalizable, its not as direct as seeing any vector as linear combination of eigen vectors. Still we do have the notion, that if there is an eigen vector and has a corresponding negative eigen value, then (ignoring rest of space) at least that span of eigen vector will need to move to negative side of its normal plane in the transformation, and we will have to do flipping for that. Sill, what information is abstracted by dependent eigen vectors, is away from me!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck in your studies. I think you will like learning about SVD, when you get to that.

Comment: @BhartenduKumar "So. what I did was hold the tip of vector $j$ from $[0,1]$ and glide it to left to the point $[3,1]$"  now try doing the same for $i$ and $j$ simultaneously.  Do they cross over?

Comment: @L.F. Wow! Yes doing simultaneously, they cross! But what all meaning I could infer by the crossing? And by flipping hownare we avoiding this crossing if at all they are still in the same plane? And how this crossng idea is also represented by a negative eigenvalue? Like how the negative eigen value can see that the transformation is making gridlines cross? Thank you

Comment: @BhartenduKumar We are not *avoiding* the crossing by flipping; rather, flipping is the *result* of this crossing.  When $i$ and $j$ cross during the motion, other vectors in the plane cross as well; the flipping of the plane is the manifestation of parts of the plane crossing each other.

Comment: @BhartenduKumar As for eigenvalues, you'll get a deeper understanding by watching episode 14.  Simply put, eigenvectors are vectors that don't leave the line they are located on during the transformation, and the amount by which their magnitude is scaled is their corresponding eigenvalue, with negative eigenvalues representing crossing over the origin.  (For example, a scaling by $-1$ places a vector in its opposite direction.)